# NGINX memory spiking when caching

Tags: caching, memory, nginx

I am fairly new to NGINX and trying to setup caching, although I am able to get caching work I am running into a memory usage problem. Now in the NGINX documentation it says that NGINX can store around 8000 cache keys within 1MB space. So with the config I have I ran a load test with 20K unique requests. Very quickly I see that the memory usage on the NGINX boxes spiked to 70MB. Now as per the documentation I would imagine that the memory usage to be much lower than what I am seeing. Also I confirmed that the memory usage is spiking only when I turn on caching.

Here is the caching part of my NGINX config:

```
proxy_cache_path /tmp/cache keys_zone=static:4000m max_size=10g inactive=12h;
proxy_cache static;
add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
proxy_ignore_headers X-Accel-Expires Expires Set-Cookie;
proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control;
proxy_cache_min_uses 1;
proxy_cache_key '$scheme$host$uri';
proxy_cache_valid 200 12h;
```

Can someone please help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem of Nginx on Windows.

On Linux this behavior is not experienced, it caches ~8K requests per 1Mb keys_zone size, as expected.

On Windows cache behaves differently.

Note the remark on [Nginx site](http://nginx.org/en/docs/windows.html#known_issues):

> "The cache and other modules which require shared memory support do
>   not work on Windows Vista and later versions .."

Without looking into sources, I can't even say whether the cache with memory sharing is working properly on Windows at all, even given enough space.

From my tests, until you hit file count limits below, it serves from cache as expected. It probably requires 4K (page size) for each key allocation in zone on Windows.

I tested with 25K requests and the maximum number of files that are retained in cache is proportional to the keys_zone size as follows:

```
1m  <= 253 files 
2m  <= 508 files 
3m  <= 761 
5m  <= 1274 
10m <= 2548 
20m <= 5103 
40m <= ~8K 
80m <= ~20K
```

(numbers are for 1.9.3,  1.11.6 exposes similar behavior with slightly different numbers).

This is consistent with your memory growth observation. Once you reach file count limit per keys_zone size as above, it is going to miss weirdly.

On Ubuntu, Nginx 1.4 and 1.10 do create expected number of cache files with respect to limit; process memory for 25K cached requests does not grow far beyond ~1Mb per 8k requests, as expected.